# Amazon S3 image download by bytearray in java and convert to base64 in javascript different value

Tags: arrays, reactjs, spring, amazon-web-services, base64

### **1.send byte array from java and convert base64 in javascript**

==java code(spring)==

```
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> download(String key) throws IOException {
   
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyId, secretKeyId);
    AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
            .withRegion(clientRegion).build();

    GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key);
    S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(getObjectRequest);
    S3ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(objectInputStream);
    String fileName = URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%20");
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    httpHeaders.setContentLength(bytes.length);
    httpHeaders.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", fileName);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(bytes, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

↑ aws image download code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/image/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> imageDownload(String key) throws IOException {

        ResponseEntity<byte[]> byteStream = awsS3.download(key);
        
        return byteStream;
    }
}
```

↑ return image byte array

==javascript code(react)==

```
        const result = await GetAPI("/api/image/download?key=housing/userid/1626770531982_1536568681_3.jpg");

        console.log('result',result);

        const array = new Uint32Array(Buffer.from(result.data,"binary"));

        console.log('window.btoa(array)',window.btoa(array));
```

↑ convert byte array to base64

[image]

↑ convert byte array to base64 result captured image

============================================================================

### **2. send base64 from java and check in javascript**

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/image/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String imageDownload(String key) throws IOException {

```
  ResponseEntity<byte[]> byteStream = awsS3.download(key); byte[]
  encodedByteStream = com.amazonaws.util.Base64.encode(byteStream.getBody());
  String base64DataString = new String(encodedByteStream, "UTF-8");
  
  return base64DataString;
```

}

↑ send base64 to javascript

[image]

↑ send base64 to javascript captured image

### question : why is it different the value of converted in java then send to javascript and the value of sending to javascript from java then convered in javascript?

sorry my english.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old Java API for this use case. To get an object in an Amazon S3 bucket as bytes, you should consider using the AWS SDK for Java V2.

Here is Amazon S3 Java V2 code that uses the **s3.getObjectAsBytes** method to get an object as a byte[].

```
private S3Client getClient() {
    // Create the S3Client object
    Region region = Region.US_WEST_2;
    S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.create())
            .region(region)
            .build();

    return s3;
  }

public byte[] getObjectBytes (String bucketName, String keyName) {

    s3 = getClient();

    try {
        // Create a GetObjectRequest instance
        GetObjectRequest objectRequest = GetObjectRequest
                .builder()
                .key(keyName)
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .build();

        // Get the byte[] from this S3 object
        ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> objectBytes = s3.getObjectAsBytes(objectRequest);
        byte[] data = objectBytes.asByteArray();
        return data;

    } catch (S3Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Replace your V1 code with this V2 code and then use Java encoding logic.

If you are not familiar with working with AWS SDK for Java V2, I recommend starting here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html